# While debugging in WCF method getting error such as {"Must declare the scalar variable \"@POL_NBR\"."}

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, stored-procedures

Error type is System.Data.Sqlclient.SqlException - {"Must declare the scalar variable "@POL_NBR"."}

I am having one column name with POL_NBR in gridview in Winform and I am trying to debug while updating few columns value meanwhile this error is throwing up like must declare a scalar variable. But I have already declared it in my SPs and also naming convention perfect,there is no spelling mistake.

Here it  is in my WCF method

```
sqlParameter[2] = new SqlParameter("@POL_NBR", SqlDbType.VarChar,50, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 10, 0, "POL_NBR", DataRowVersion.Current, POL_NBR);
```

and My Update SP is as below

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [UpdateInputData]
    @tbl_pol_id int,
    @LOB varchar (50) = null,
    @POL_NBR varchar(50)=null
    
    
    AS
    
    BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    
    
    Declare @LOBID INT
    
    
    SELECT @LOBID = TBL_LOB_TYP_LKUP_ID FROM TBL_LOB_TYP_LKUP WHERE Upper(ltrim(rtrim(LOB_NM))) = Upper(ltrim(rtrim(@LOB)))
    
    BEGIN
    
    
    Declare @sql_Query varchar(8000) = null
    
    set @sql_Query = 'Update TPCA set'
    
    if(@POL_NBR is not null and @POL_NBR <> '')
    
    Begin 
    
    set @sql_Query = @sql_Query + ' TPCA.POL_NBR = @POL_NBR'
    
   
    End
```

Comment: The problem is using dynamic SQL inside the procedure, and assuming `@POL_NBR` is still available in the inner scope. It's not. It's quite unclear why you think an `UPDATE` statement has to be built dynamically here anyway. I also assume a bunch of code is missing, like the part that adds a `WHERE` and actually executes the query. Consider not using dynamic SQL (seems completely unnecessary here) and just using `IF .. UPDATE ... ELSE UPDATE ....` if you must have different forms of the statement. Alternatively, use `sp_executesql` to pass the outer value as a parameter to the inner query.

Comment: How to write if else with update for POL_NBR any reference please